# Problem to run MVC 3.0 application with IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have created application using:
Default Web Site >> Right Click >> Add Application

Added following details
Alias : CAFM
Physical Path: path of my application
Application pool: ASP.Net v4.0

Now i type following in Internet Explorer, then it is working fine.
http://localhost/cafm/Authentication/logon

**Routing Code:**

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("Default.aspx");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Authentication", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

**Problem:** 
If i type only following in internet explorer then it is giving me an error
http://localhost/cafm/

**Error:**
The resource cannot be found.
**Description:** HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

**Requested URL:** /cafm/

Please help me, how could i set default page to Authentication if user type only http://localhost/cafm.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!
Thanks
Imdadhusen

Comment: Could you please post your routes in your mvc application?

Comment: i have updated code as per your suggestion.

Comment: is `cafm` an application folder?

Comment: Yes, my virtual directory name is CAFM and application physical path is D:/projects/CAFM.Web/Views/Authentication and Authentication contains following pages (.cshtml) ChangePassword, ChangePasswordSuccess, LogOn and Register. I hope now you clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be your route should point to action `LogOn` not `Index`

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Authentication", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Lg
warappa

Comment: You are 100% correct. i got the problem... Thank you very much